# How can I create aggregate expressions of this list of dicts?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, aggregate

I have a list of dictionaries that expresses periods+days for a class in a student information system. Here's the data I'd like to aggregate:

```
[
    {
        'period': {
            'name': '1',
            'sort_order': 1
        },
        'day': {
            'name': 'A',
            'sort_order': 1
        }
    },
    {
        'period': {
            'name': '1',
            'sort_order': 1
        },
        'day': {
            'name': 'B',
            'sort_order': 2
        }
    },
    {
        'period': {
            'name': '1',
            'sort_order': 1
        },
        'day': {
            'name': 'C',
            'sort_order': 1
        }
    },
    {
        'period': {
            'name': '3',
            'sort_order': 3
        },
        'day': {
            'name': 'A',
            'sort_order': 1
        }
    },
    {
        'period': {
            'name': '3',
            'sort_order': 3
        },
        'day': {
            'name': 'B',
            'sort_order': 2
        }
    },
    {
        'period': {
            'name': '3',
            'sort_order': 3
        },
        'day': {
            'name': 'C',
            'sort_order': 2
        }
    },
    {
        'period': {
            'name': '4',
            'sort_order': 4
        },
        'day': {
            'name': 'D',
            'sort_order': 3
        }
    }
]
```

The aggregated string I'd like the above to reduce to is `1,3(A-C) 4(D)`. Notice that objects that aren't "adjacent" (determined by the object's `sort_order`) to each other are delimited by `,` and "adjacent" records  are delimited by a `-`.

### EDIT

Let me try to elaborate on the aggregation process. Each "class meeting" object contains a period and day. There are usually ~5 periods per day, and the days alternate cyclically between A,B,C,D, etc. So if I have a class that occurs 1st period on an A day, we might express that as 1(A). If a class occurs on 1st and 2nd period on an A day, the raw form of that might be 1(A),2(A), but it can be shortened to 1-2(A).

Some classes might not be in "adjacent" periods or days. A class might occur on 1st period and 3rd period on an A day, so its short form would be 1,3(A). However, if that class were on 1st, 2nd, and 3rd period on an A day, it could be written as 1-3(A). This also applies to days, so if a class occurs on 1st,2nd, and 3rd period, on A,B, and C day, then we could write it 1-3(A-C).

Finally, if a class occurs on 1st,2nd, and 3rd period and on A,B, and C day, but also on 4th period on D day, its short form would be `1-3(A-C) 4(D)`.

### What I've tried

The first step that occurs to me to perform is to "group" the meeting objects into related sub-lists with the following function:

```
def _to_related_lists(list):
    """Given a list of section meeting dicts, return a list of lists, where each sub-list is list of
    related section meetings, either related by period or day"""

    related_list = []
    sub_list = []

    related_values = set()
    for index, section_meeting_object in enumerate(list):
        # starting with empty values list
        if not related_values:
            related_values.add(section_meeting_object['period']['name'])
            related_values.add(section_meeting_object['day']['name'])
            sub_list.append(section_meeting_object)
        elif section_meeting_object['period']['name'] in related_values or section_meeting_object['day']['name'] in related_values:
            related_values.add(section_meeting_object['period']['name'])
            related_values.add(section_meeting_object['day']['name'])
            sub_list.append(section_meeting_object)
        else:
            # no related values found in current section_meeting_object
            related_list.append(sub_list)
            sub_list = []
            related_values = set()
            related_values.add(section_meeting_object['period']['name'])
            related_values.add(section_meeting_object['day']['name'])
            sub_list.append(section_meeting_object)

    related_list.append(sub_list)

    return related_list
```

Which returns:

```
[
    [{
        'period': {
            'sort_order': 1,
            'name': '1'
        },
        'day': {
            'sort_order': 1,
            'name': 'A'
        }
    }, {
        'period': {
            'sort_order': 1,
            'name': '1'
        },
        'day': {
            'sort_order': 2,
            'name': 'B'
        }
    }, {
        'period': {
            'sort_order': 2,
            'name': '2'
        },
        'day': {
            'sort_order': 1,
            'name': 'A'
        }
    }, {
        'period': {
            'sort_order': 2,
            'name': '2'
        },
        'day': {
            'sort_order': 2,
            'name': 'B'
        }
    }],
    [{
        'period': {
            'sort_order': 4,
            'name': '4'
        },
        'day': {
            'sort_order': 3,
            'name': 'C'
        }
    }]
]
```

If the entire string `1-3(A-C) 4(D)` is the aggregate expression I'd like in the end, let's call `1-3(A-C)` and `4(D)` "sub-expressions". Each related sub-list would be a "sub-expression", so I was thinking I'd somehow iterate through every sublist and create the sub-expression, but I"m not exactly sure how to do that.

Comment: I did not understand a word.

Comment: The relationship between your inputs and outputs is confusing at best. How would the output string be formed if, for example, `B` corresponded to only `2` and `3` rather than `1-3`?

Comment: @asongtoruin the output would be `1(A) 2-3(A-B)`

Comment: There's no significance to `sort-order`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us define your list as `d_list`.

```
d_list = [
    {'period': {'sort_order': 1, 'name': '1'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 1, 'name': 'A'}},
    {'period': {'sort_order': 1, 'name': '1'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 2, 'name': 'B'}},
    {'period': {'sort_order': 1, 'name': '1'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 1, 'name': 'C'}},
    {'period': {'sort_order': 3, 'name': '3'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 1, 'name': 'A'}},
    {'period': {'sort_order': 3, 'name': '3'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 2, 'name': 'B'}},
    {'period': {'sort_order': 3, 'name': '3'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 2, 'name': 'C'}},
    {'period': {'sort_order': 4, 'name': '4'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 3, 'name': 'D'}},
]
```

Note that I use the python native module [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) to define that `B` is between `A` and `C`. Thus what you may want to do is

```
import string

agg0 = {}
for d in d_list:
    name = d['period']['name']
    if name not in agg0:
        agg0[name] = []
    day = d['day']
    agg0[name].append(day['name'])

agg1 = {}
for k,v in agg0.items():
    pos_in_alph = [string.ascii_lowercase.index(el.lower()) for el in v]
    allowed_indexes = [max(pos_in_alph),min(pos_in_alph)]
    agg1[k] = [el for el in v if string.ascii_lowercase.index(el.lower()) in allowed_indexes]

agg = {}
for k,v in agg1.items():
    w = tuple(v)
    if w not in agg:
        agg[w] = {'ks':[],'gr':len(agg0[k])>2}
    agg[w]['ks'].append(k)
    print agg[w]

str_ = ''
for k,v in sorted(agg.items(), key=lambda item:item[0], reverse=False):
    str_ += ' {pnames}({dnames})'.format(pnames=('-' if v['gr'] else ',').join(sorted(v['ks'])),
                                         dnames='-'.join(k))

print(str_.strip())
```

which outputs  `1-3(A-C) 4(D)`

---

Following @NathanJones's comment, note that if `d_list` were defined as

```
d_list = [
    {'period': {'sort_order': 1, 'name': '1'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 1, 'name': 'A'}},
    ##{'period': {'sort_order': 1, 'name': '1'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 2, 'name': 'B'}},
    {'period': {'sort_order': 1, 'name': '1'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 1, 'name': 'C'}},
    {'period': {'sort_order': 3, 'name': '3'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 1, 'name': 'A'}},
    {'period': {'sort_order': 3, 'name': '3'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 2, 'name': 'B'}},
    {'period': {'sort_order': 3, 'name': '3'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 2, 'name': 'C'}},
    {'period': {'sort_order': 4, 'name': '4'}, 'day': {'sort_order': 3, 'name': 'D'}},
]
```

The code above would print `1,3(A-C) 4(D)`

Comment: The `sort_order` field in each `day` object is meant to denote that `B` is between `A` and `C`.

Comment: When I try to run this, I get this error: `AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'lowercase'`

Comment: Thanks for updating it to python 3.

Comment: Almost. I don't think it's using `sort_order` because my output is `3-1(A-C) 4(D)`

Comment: Also I don't think this solution would account for adjacent period/days vs non-adjacent ones.

Comment: If periods 1 and 3, but not 2, were included in the course's meeting records, i think it would still display `1-3`, not `1,3` as it should.

Comment: @NathanJones It will do now. Check it.